# How to develop wingpanel extension in plain C language?

Tags: development, elementary-project

I am trying to find a way to develop **wingpanel extension** in **plain C** code.
Every time that I asked question about app development in elementary OS, They just said that you should learn Vala language. Why should I learn Vala language when the platform for developing elementary app is GKT & GTK is completely written in C language & has C base api. So please help me. I really need this. I am really tired of learning new language & new build system & new api & ... .

Answer (score 1):

Build the sample indicator and look at the generated c code.
https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/tree/master/sample

https://stackoverflow.com/a/653413

Comment: Thank you for response & your time. I hoped, there was official way to do this with gtk api by elementary team.

Comment: What you mean with official way? You can just use the Wingpanel API and GTK API from c.